# Error: no such column: ..... even with quote marks

Tags: sqlite, datatables, sql-insert

I am trying to build a small database for myself and I have created 4 tables however I'm having issues inserting into the tables:

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE Year (
    YearID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    date DATE NOT NULL,
    item TEXT NOT NULL,
    income FLOAT NOT NULL,
    expense FLOAT NOT NULL
);
```

This is on of the tables that I have created and when I run this:

```
INSERT INTO Year (yearID, date, item, income, expense) 
          VALUES (2018, 17/12/2018, ‘testing’, 1000, 500);
```

I get the error:

> Error: no such column: 'testing'

I'm not sure why this is can anyone help?

P.S I know I'm not inserting the date right either but one problem at a time :)

Thanks,
Totally Confused :)

Comment: The date should be in single quotes, as should the string `‘testing’`, because the Unicode smart quotes currently surrounding it are not the ascii single quote `'` character that should be there.

Comment: Also, using the date format `YYYY-MM-DD` will make your life much easier (and use TEXT instead of the non-existent DATE column type: https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype ).

Comment: Also, you should be using `INTEGER` instead of `INT` for that primary key: https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid

Comment: You guys are legends thanks heaps :)